# Config Issue with dyndns windows updater

Tags: dynamic-dns

I'm unable to open website xyz.dyndns.org internally as well as externally. I have UTStarCom ASDL Router and also did port 80 forward.

Can someone tell me why its not working?

Comment: You don't give us anywhere enough information to help you. Frankly, you really will probably need to list the full DNS name.

Comment: Here is the full DNS name  [nodebuzz.dyndns.info](http://nodebuzz.dyndns.info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the first thing you need to make sure of is that your Router or other method of updating your DDNS is working.

I did and `NSLOOKUP` of your domain and it points to `59.93.16.14`. So now on one of your computers, go to http://www.whatismyip.com/ and make sure it matches that IP address.

If it does, you have a router configuration problem. I could not `telnet 59.93.16.14 80` so as of now, the port is actually closed on that IP address.

I would make sure that you have a static IP address set internally for the port forwarding, and then see if you can figure out what is wrong with your port forwarding configuration.

If you post back some screenshots of the appropriate areas, and the exact model of your router, I can try to guide you more.

Comment: [apacherunningmakesureport80isopen](http://www.uploadfiles.org/apacherunningmakesureport80isopen) [dyndnsupdaterrunningforwindows](http://www.uploadfiles.org/dyndnsupdaterrunningforwindows) [openportchecktool80-nodebuzzdyndnsinfo](http://www.uploadfiles.org/openportchecktool80-nodebuzzdyndnsinfo) [http://www.uploadfiles.org/routername-name-ut300r2u](http://www.uploadfiles.org/routername-name-ut300r2u) [http://www.uploadfiles.org/setmanagementportto61001](http://www.uploadfiles.org/setmanagementportto61001)  [usingpfconfigtodoportforward](http://www.uploadfiles.org/usingpfconfigtodoportforward)

Comment: I have attached few screenshots, also my ISP changes IP address dynamically, its not static, As per dyndns.org I have installed dyndns updater to support dynamic ip. Again RouterName = UT300R2U, Its a asdl router  (utSTARcom )

Comment: I asked my friend to upvote your question, so in the future, you can just click the little image icon (in edit or new question mode), and upload your pictures directly into the question.

Comment: OK, your DDNS part is definitely working 100%. I was also able to get to port 80 ("It works!" was displayed). What is still not working specifically? Or what are you trying to do exactly/

Comment: well when I try to do the same inside [http://nodebuzz.dyndns.info/](http://nodebuzz.dyndns.info/) of my LAN network it doesn't work. I don't see any response. Is it because the router blocks the external ip.

Comment: You are encountering a problem I always have problems remembering the name of. Yes, most times, you have to access the web server using the internal IP addess (or internal DNS name), and that is why you are having problems. Go here to test your site externally: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/